How to make browser display PDF and then use custom filename when downloading
I want to preview pdf first and then let user download by themselves, also provide default name when downloading.
This is the code:
var data = fs.readFileSync('/Users/my/Desktop/demo.pdf');
res.contentType("application/pdf");
//   res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=my.pdf');
res.send(data);

Here if I do not set fileName, it will preview immediately in browser, but if I set fileName, it will download immediately.

Does this answer your question? Display PDF within web browser

When setting Content-Disposition header, along with your filename, use the inline parameter, which will tell browser to try to display content, instead of attachment parameter, which tells browser to download content, and as inline is the default value, you can omit it:
var data = fs.readFileSync('/Users/my/Desktop/demo.pdf');
res.contentType("application/pdf");
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'filename=my.pdf');
//res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=my.pdf');
res.send(data);

see: Content-Disposition # As a response header for the main body

The first parameter in the HTTP context is either
inline (default value, indicating it can be displayed
inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or attachment
(indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save
as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename
parameters if present).

